# GLFW fails on Debian (with Python)

Tags: opengl, glfw, xvfb, glx

I tried to make the question as reproducible as possible. So here is the docker commands:

```
docker run --name headless_test -ti python:3.6-jessie /bin/bash
```

And inside the docker execute the following lines:

```
apt update && apt install -y git xvfb xorg-dev cmake
pip3 install glfw
mkdir /projects
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git /projects/glfw
cd /projects/glfw
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
export PYGLFW_LIBRARY=/projects/glfw/src/libglfw.so
xvfb-run python -c "import glfw; glfw.init(); glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, False); glfw.create_window(100, 100, 'hidden window', None, None)"
```

this fails with the following error:

```
GLX: Failed to find a suitable GLXFBConfig
```

executing `xvfb-run glxinfo` (after installing `mesa-utils`) returns the following:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

EDIT: This works great if I use the `ubuntu` docker

Comment: So does it work in other Linux distributions inside Docker?

Comment: edited- it works on ubuntu

Comment: Yes. It is automatically installed as part of the previous steps (executing `apt install libgl1-mesa-glx` changes nothing)